# inverse of sobolev riemannian metric still sobolev?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Given a covariant riemannian metric of certain sobolev class (i.e. with square-integrable weak derivatives up to a large enough integer order) on a (compact, if necessary) finite-dimensional smooth manifold, I would like to know the answers to the following related questions:

(1) does its inverse (i.e. the contra-variant type) belong to the same sobolev class?

(2) If a sequence of (covariant) metrics converges in the given sobolev norm to a limit metric, does it follow that the sequence of corresponding inverse metrics converges in the same sobolev norm to the inverse of the above limit metric?

***One of the things that I am iffy about: the inverse of a non-degenerate matrix involves the reciprocal of its determinant. I can believe that the determinant of a metric is a nowhere vanishing sobolev function but I am not sure whether it holds true for its reciprocal.

Thanks very much!

Comment: If you have large enough order to get, by Sobolev embedding, that the metric is in $L^\infty$, then the question is an issue of arithmetic. // In general, your question is basically the same as asking "if the function $f\in W^{s,p}$ then is the function $1/f \in W^{s,p}$?"

Comment: yes. my knowledge of analysis is at most epsilon above zero.

Comment: yes, it is essentially about taking the reciprocal of a sobolev function as you pointed out. My knowledge of analysis is at most epsilon above zero, intuition appears to lead me to hope that the inverse metric is still sobolev but math may prove otherwise For what I care about at the moment, p=2, s>n/2+1 or n/2+2, where n is the dimension of the manifold. I feel that this must be a basic general fact but I am too ignorant to know...

Comment: On a domain of dimension $n$, if you allow $k$ derivatives and $kp > n$ you have (Sobolev embedding) that $W^{k,p}$ functions automatically admit a representative in $C^0$. Applying this to your metric you have that on every compact region the metric determinant is bounded away from zero and from infinity, and hence also the determinant of the inverse. The same argument that tells you that $W^{k,p}$ is an algebra (under pointwise multiplication) in this case will also tell you that your inverse metric is also in $W^{k,p}$.

Comment: These are mostly discussed in Section 5.6 of L.C. Evans' _Partial Differential Equations_; the statement that $W^{k,p}$ is an algebra is relegated to an exercise at the end of the chapter.

Comment: I did read about the embedding into $C^0$ and the so called Shauder ring property. I guess I was initially afraid that just because the function itself is bounded away from zero and infinity, there is no control of its derivatives when taking the $L^2$ norms (eg. its derivatives might not be square integrable?). So it is true that more generally the reciprocal of a nowhere vanishing sobolev function is also sobolev?  and the answers to both questions would be yes? P. S. Thank you Mr. Wong for your help!!

Comment: sorry Mr. Yang, I know I am riding a bicycle to the moon. As a beginner, I am hoping to be able to learn little by little as I go. I sincerely appreciate the generous help and guidance provided by experts like you.

Comment: For first derivatve: $(1/f)' = -f' / f^2$ so $\| (1/f)'\|_{L^2} \leq \| 1/f\|_{L^\infty}^2 \|f'\|_{L^2}$. For second derivative $(1/f)'' = - f'' / f^2 + 2 (f')^2 / f^3$. To get $L^2$ integrability you need $f'$ is in $L^4$, but this, when $kp > n$, follows from Sobolev embedding and interpolation. Same for higher derivatives.

Comment: For some reason, I find it easier to understand the general case, rather than for just the function $t \mapsto 1/t$. Instead, assume that you have a smooth function $\Phi: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and you want to prove that if $f$ lies in a Sobolev space and its image lies in $(a,b)$, then $\Phi\circ f$ lies in the same Sobolev space.